# Determine vector $A$ perpendicular to plane, and $B$ parallel to plane such that $A + B = (-1,0,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given plane $P: x + 2y + 3z = 1$, find $A$ and $B$ such that $A+B=(-1,0,1)$ with $A$ perpendicular to $P$, $B$ parallel to $P$.

Vector $A$ must be perpendicular to this plane, and $B$ must be parallel.
$A + B = (-1,0,1)$

Vector $A$ must be $(1,2,3)$, right? Or some scalar multiple of it.
I can't figure out how to get $B$, and I've been trying for hours.
P.S.: we haven't covered cross products (if that would even be useful)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**
Your idea about $A$ is correct. $A$ will be some scalar multiple of $(1,2,3)$. so write $A=(k,2k,3k)$.
Also as $A+B=(-1,0,1)$, write $B=(-1,0,1)-(k,2k,3k)=(-1-k,-2k,1-3k)$.

Note $B$ is parallel to the plane, so it must be perpendicular to $(1,2,3)$, i.e. $(1,2,3)\cdot (-1-k,-2k,1-3k)=0$.